# Sensitivity and specificity for multiple raters

Tags: sensitivity-specificity

I am conducting a study where 3 raters assessed performance of two similar test in regards to classify a lesion as malignant vs. benign. I wish to calculate specificity and sensitivity of each test with regards to golden standard. For example, I was thinking of adding all raters true positives and dividing those by the sum of all raters true positives and false negatives. But is this the right way to do it?